# Integrando InAppBrowser com BarcodeScanner

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin, inappbrowser

Olá, estou com um problema que não consigo resolver. Estou utilizando o plugin inAppBrowser e necessito que quando o usuário clicar em determinado botão dentro do navegador gerado, o plugin seja fechado e simultaneamente seja aberto um leitor de código QR.

## O que ja tentei fazer:

Como se trata de um navegador gerado internamente, implementei bibliotecas que abrem a câmera e fazem a leitura por sí mesmas. No entanto, quando a página é aberta com o inappBrowser recebo uma exceção de permissão negada. Pensando que era apenas uma permissão de câmera adicionei a seguinte configuração:

#### AndroidManifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

#### home.ts

```
constructor
  (
    private camera: Camera,
    private androidPermissions : AndroidPermissions,
    private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser
  ) {}
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.verificapermissao();
  }
  verificapermissao(){
    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      clearcache:'yes',
      hardwareback:'yes',
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:'yes'
    }
    console.log(options)

    this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
      result => {
        console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission)
        this.inAppBrowser.create('meuURL', '_self', options)
      },
      err => this.verificapermissao()
    );
  }
```

Utilizei o plugin AndroidPermissions para forçar o usuário permitir acesso a câmera, no entanto sem sucesso.

## O que necessito agora:

Como disse anteriormente preciso de fazer que o app encerre o inAppBrowser e abra o leitor, quando a leitura for encerrada, o usuário seja redirecionado a uma url  com os dados recebidos pelo scanner passados por parâmetros. Caso não seja possivel isso preciso pelo menos conseguir dar a permissão para o navegador interno do inAppBrowser.

## Ambiente de desenvolvimento:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.15.0 (C:\Users\micro-85\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.9
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Você quer dizer que esta a todo momento entrando no `err => this.verificapermissao()`? Ou é alguma mensagem de erro vindo especificamente do `barcode.xhtml`?

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pelo comentário, isso é apenas para forçar a pessoa a aceitar a permissão pois quando ela clicar ser feita a solicitação de permissão novamente. Mas isso nçao funcionou pois quando abre a biblioteca do barcode recebo no console uma mensagem de exception de permissão negada. Queria saber se de alguma forma poderia pausar o inappBRowser para abrir o leitor do celular.

Comment: Bom, não estou certo que a permissão propague para um dominio fora do dominio local da aplicação, não sei exatamente porque precisou fazer dessa forma ao invés de usar diretamente embutido no projeto, como no exemplo: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/ -- existe algum motivo para estar usando uma página web externa?

Comment: Foi desenvolvido uma aplicação em webview e então precisávamos de inclui-lo no app. Você saberia como faço para parar o appInBrowser quando clicasse em algum botão no html ? Isso para mim ja seria suficiente, pois depois prosseguiria em outra url

Comment: Hérick, estou enferrujado de Cordova e cia, mas é quase certo que isso é algo InAppBrower estar limitado, porque se me recordo isso teria que ser resolvido na parte "java", mas não vou entrar em detalhes, o que encontrei que talvez possa lhe resolver o problema seja isso: https://github.com/jverlee/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera

Comment: De mesma forma, muito obrigado.